# Why does find in MATLAB return indices as double values?

Tags: matlab, indexing, integer, find, return-type

The `find` function in MATLAB returns indices where the given logical argument evaluates true.

Thus I'm wondering, why are the returned indices of type `double` and not `uint32` or `uint64` like the biggest index into a matrix could be?

Another strange thing which might be connected to that here is, that running

```
[~,max_num_of_elem] = computer
```

returns the maximal number of elements allowed for a matrix in the variable `max_num_of_elem` which is also of type `double`.

Comment: `find` can return indices **and** values. I assume you are asking about the data type of the indices, not the values.

Comment: Oh, sorry am304 - of course you are right. I'll adopt the question accordingly.

Comment: `double` is Matlab's native type. Almost everything uses it and returns it. This was a design choice and in many cases make it a lot easier as one can directly use the values returned in equations without having to convert them. The only issue is that `find` likely won't work for for matrices with more than `2^53` elements.

Comment: @horchler: actually the [maximum number of elements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/computer.html) on 64-bit architectures is `2^48 -1`. That is still way more than anything you'll ever need, as it amounts to a vector of 256 tera one-byte elements ((2^48-1)/2^40 = 256) or a `double` vector of size 32TB (terabytes as in 1024 GB!). Keep in mind that on Windows, that is even larger than the memory limit allowed by the OS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx . So I dont see the problem here :)

Comment: @Amro: Well that's good news for `find` then. I was simply quoting the largest double integer before they start not all having exact floating-point representations.

Comment: @horchler: yes that's true, double-precision floating-point numbers have significand with 52+1 bits of precision. So the range of exactly representable integers is `[-2^53,+2^53]`. Beyond this, the spacing starts to double for every range `[2^n,2^(n+1)]`. That's why `eps(2^53)==2`, `eps(2^54)==4`, and so on.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 6):

I can only guess, but probably because a wide range of functions only support `double`. Run

```
setdiff(methods('double'), methods('uint32'))
```

to see what functions are defined for `double` and not for `uint32` on your version of MATLAB.

Also there is the [overflow issue with integer data types in MATLAB](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/uint8.html) that can introduce some hard to detect bugs.

Comment: probably also because of historical reasons; MATLAB originally only had `double` type, and it was not until later releases that other types were introduced: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/01/15/data-types/